# Gradle intellij отсутствует Store generated project files externall

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle

Здравствуйте уважаемые, такая проблема. Осваиваю градл, запускаю градл проект с интелии и у меня отсутствует Store generated project files externally.
После создания проекта приходится вручную прописывать все папки src - main - java. При этом библиотеки градлом не подгружаются. 
При этом на всех видео уроках у всех есть такая функция. Может вопрос дурацкий - я не знаю, только учу градл.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: При создании проекта ошибок небыло? Возможно в визарде создания проекта вы выбрали Java старой версии, а современному гредлу требуется минимум 8

Comment: При запуске выдает Error: Could not find or load main class main
У меня JDK 1.8 OS Ubuntu